# How to Spy on angular forkJoin for multiple response in unit test - Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am working on the unit testing,i have one function which calls multiple API in one shot.I have written **spyOn** on the service function but  I am not able to return multiple response.Can any one please suggest where i am missing ?

component.ts

```
 loadMappedVendorDoc() {
    this.destroySearch$ = this.apiServ.cloneSubscribe();
    this.isDataLoading = true;
    const curdAPIsJoin = [
      this.apiServ.awsGet('api_path_one),
      this.authSer.awsGet('api_path_two')];

    forkJoin(curdAPIsJoin).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroySearch$)).subscribe(reps => {
      this.isDataLoading = false;
      if (reps[0].status_code === '200') {
        this.originalmappedDocTypeData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(reps[0].response));
        this.mappedDocTypeData = reps[0].response;
      } else {
        this.mappedDocTypeData = [];
      }
      if (reps[1].status_code === '200') {
        this.authSer.ihsDocType = reps[1].response;
      } else {
        this.authSer.ihsDocType = [];
      }
    });
  }
```

Note:  **awsGet** returns the observable

component.spec.ts

```
  it('loadMappedVendorDoc shoud call', fakeAsync(() => {
        spyOn(apiService, 'awsGet').and.returnValue(of([{ status_code: '200', response: mappedStub }, { status_code: '200', response: mappedStub2 }]));
        component.originalmappedDocTypeData = mappedStub;
        component.mappedDocTypeData = mappedStub;
        component.loadMappedVendorDoc();
    
       fixture.detectChanges();
        tick(1000);
        expect(component.mappedDocTypeData.length).toBe(3);
        // flush();
    
      }));
```

Note: **mappedStub** is dummy response

Problem Statement:In code coverage if block is not executing because of that data is not displaying on the page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved using following code block

```
 spyOn(apiService, 'awsGet')
      .withArgs('api_path_one').and.returnValue(of({ status_code: '200', response: modalInfoStub }))
      .withArgs('api_path_two').and.returnValue(of({ status_code: '200', response: doctype }));
```

find more about **[withArgs](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Spy.html)**